# Using Box Cloud Storage for Spree e-commerce

Tags: amazon-s3, e-commerce, assets, spree, box

I am currently creating an online store with the Spree e-commerce system and want to deploy it to `Heroku`. As stated [here](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/heroku.html), `Heroku` is read-only and thus I need to configure my app that it uploads its assets to another server.

It it suggested to use `Amazon S3`, which I cannot use since I do not own a credit card, so I decided to use `Box`. My problem is that the tutorial only describes how to use Spree with Amazon S3, and I can't find a corresponding section in the documentation.

In the site mentioned above, it is said that the app should be configured as follows (in `config/initializers/spree.rb`):

```
Spree.config do |config|
  config.use_s3 = true
  config.s3_bucket = '<bucket>'
  config.s3_access_key = "<key>"
  config.s3_secret = "<secret>"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Spree uses Paperclip for storing images.  Paperclip supports 3 storage methods:

1. File Storage
2. AWS S3 Storage (Native Support)
3. Fog Storage

Fog is a cloud based abstraction library which allows you to interface with a number of different cloud based storage (and other service) provides.

Box Cloud Storage is not currently supported by Fog.  A list of providers currently supported is provided on the [Fog Provider Documenation Website](http://fog.io/about/provider_documentation.html).

In order to get this to work, you will need to either add Box Cloud Storage support to Fog, or switch to a provider supported by Fog.